Pytorch, use loss that don't return gradient
I'm trying to develop a model that improves the quality of a given audio. For this task I use DAC for the latent space and I run a transformer model to change the value of the latent space to improve the audio. Then I use the decoder of the DAC model to decode the audio and generate the waveform. So what I do is: noise audio > Encode audio > latent space A > transformer model (that I train) > latent space B > Decode audio > denoised audio
I want to test the approach of training my transformer model on the raw audio itself (not on the latent space B) so I need to decode the audio generated during the training and then use the L1 loss between the noised audio and the denoised generated audio. The problem is that I can't keep the gradient of my transformer during the decoding process (too much RAM used and I don't want to train the decoder). I know that PyTorch uses the chain rule to compute the gradient but why does it need to know the gradient of the decoder to change the weights of my model? The decoding process is only useful to compute the loss so I can imagine that the chain rule stops at the end of my transformer model. It can compute the gradient on the result of my L1 loss and then change the weights of the transformer model only with the result of the loss.
Currently I have the error:
loss.backward()
File "/home/jourdelune/Bureau/dev/WaveAI/AudioEnhancer/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 492, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
File "/home/jourdelune/Bureau/dev/WaveAI/AudioEnhancer/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 251, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

I have tried some approaches, but what I expect is to train my model like this:
y_hat = model(x)  # prediction of the model
y_hat = rearrange(y_hat, "b (t c) d -> b c d t", c=c, d=d)  # transform the data to have the latent space dim
loss = 0
for i in range(y_hat.shape[0]):  # for each value in the batch, DAC doesn't support decoding of batches
    with torch.no_grad():  # disable gradient because too much RAM
        z_q, _, _, _ = dataset.autoencoder.quantizer(y_hat[i].float(), None)
        decoded = dataset.autoencoder.decode(z_q)  # RAW audio
    out = l1_loss(decoded, base_waveform[i][:, :, : decoded.shape[-1]])  # compute the distance between the base waveform (target) and the decoded audio (pred)
    loss += out
loss.backward()  # backpropagation

I have tried to do:
loss = torch.tensor(loss, requires_grad=True)
loss.backward()

but the model doesn't progress at all. So my question is, is it possible to do it this way?

Pytorch uses the chain rule to compute gradients via backpropagation. This requires moving backward through the entire computational graph.
Your computational graph is roughly encoder -> decoder -> loss. This means that backproping the loss to the encoder requires going through the decoder. If you remove the decoder weights from the backprop graph, there is no way for the loss to backprop to your encoder.
You don't have to train the decoder (ie you don't need to pass the decoder weights to the optimizer param dict), but you do need to run the decoder forward pass with gradient tracking.
